# webpack $JSON.stringify.apply is not a function

Tags: json, node.js, webpack

I have successfully build using webpack for my node server with express but I can seem to find the error not a solution for this. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

**When api gets called**

```
TypeError: $JSON.stringify.apply is not a function
    at stringify (webpack:///./~/core-js/library/fn/json/stringify.js?:13:26)
    at eval (webpack:///./app/schedules/Route.js?:34:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/Project/project-    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**Part of route code**

```
.post(function (req, res) {
    let url_id = (req.params.id) ? req.params.id : null;
    let schedule = JSON.stringify(req.body.data);
    ...
```

**Webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
.filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
})
.forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
});

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'eval',
    context: __dirname + "/",
    entry: './server',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        //publicPath: '/static/',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"],
                    plugins: ["transform-runtime","transform-class-properties"]
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'json-loader',
            test: /\.json$/
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false,
            },
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.(css|less)$/),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('require("source-map-support").install();', { raw: true, entryOnly: false })
    ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty",
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        dns: 'empty'
    },
    externals: nodeModules
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems something about the way webpack wraps the JSON object for Node targets. It happened to me, and opened an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4677) on their GitHub.

I know it's not the cleanest solution - to say the least - but in the meantime you can use `eval('JSON').stringify` on your code and it will work just fine.

**EDIT:** Adding `exclude: /node_modules/` to my webpack config file for the `babel-loader` configuration fixed it for me.